# malformed config.xml error in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, config, phonegap-build, malformed

I am new at using phonegap build.
So I tried to take a built by watching videos.
And I take malformed config.wml eror. 
I checked the config file but I couldt solve problem and sometimes I take another eror message ('Error - Your package has a file or directory name that is invalid. Please view the build logs to see which file is causing this error)

I will be thankful if someone can give any advice and any help to me.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="com.razzmatazzist.myapp" version="1.0.0.1">

 <name>AOR</name>
 <description>Adventure of Ruzgar</description>
 <author></author>

 <icon src="icon-128.png" width="128" height="128" />
 <icon src="icon-256.png" width="256" height="256" gap:role="default" />

 <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />

 <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

<plugin name="cordova-build-architecture" spec="https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture.git#v1.0.1" source="git" />

<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="delete"> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> </gap:config-file>

 <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
 <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden"><true/></gap:config-file>
 <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance"><false/></gap:config-file>
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" source="npm" />

 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-httpd" />

 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
 <access origin="*" />

 <!-- Optional splash screen image, e.g.: -->
 <!-- <gap:splash src="splash.png" width="1024" height="768" /> -->

</widget>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Gxs.jpg)

Comment: Do what the error advise you: "Please view the build logs to see which file is causing this error"

Answer (score 1):

Your Config.xml is not proper/valid. Please go through following

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.startewwr" version="0.0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>AOR</name>
    <description>Adventure of Ruzgar</description>
    <author></author>
    <icon src="icon-128.png" width="128" height="128" />
    <icon src="icon-256.png" width="256" height="256" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <plugin name="cordova-build-architecture" spec="https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture.git#v1.0.1" source="git" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-httpd" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```